# Conditionally import components in Gatsby for very dynamic template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm planning to build a very dynamic single page website template for Gatsby.

The theme will have many block-types componentes (30 or more) available, like:

- Jumbotron
- JumboTron2
- JumbotronWithForm
- MapWide
- MapSquare
- ...

I intend to render the page based on an array of objects, each one having a type (like Jumbotron) to match a component and the necessary data to render it.

If I import all these componentes statically...

```
import Jumbotron from './../components/Jumbtron';
```

...they all will be included in the generated JS, which is bad because my JS will be too large.

If I use dynamic imports...

```
async componentDidMount(){
   if(jumbotronTypeRequired){
       this.jumbotron =  await import('./../components/Jumbotron');
   }
   this.setState({ dynamicComponentsLoaded: true });
}

render(){
   if(this.state.dynamicComponentsLoaded){
      //render all
   }
   else{return (<div>Loading...</div>)}
}
```

...I can only fetch the component in a Promise, this means that the component will fully rendered after the ComponentDidMount, which is bad for SEO because my resulting HTML will not contain the fully rendered data.

Does Gatsby has a way to include only the necessary components to render the dynamic page while keeping a fully rendered HTML (not just render "Loading...")?

Comment: Hum, I'm digging a little more and maybe the place to do that is in createPages method (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages). This way the components can be fetched before the page component creation.

Comment: Did you hack it?

Comment: For any Google friend, seems like this is coming to Gatsby soon https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/18689

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr to achieve this. There will however be a reference to the file path of each component in the bundle but at least the actual components do not get bundled.